# How to capture microphone input in VLC?

Tags: streaming, vlc

I'm trying to capture microphone input in VLC media player via the http interface and stream this but so far I have arrived at nothing. Is this actually possible?

Comment: which platform? I'm mac so i know for sure this is possible with VLC 2.0 for the other platforms this should work as well. haven't tested those commands though. 

Mac: Use VLC 2.0.0 or later and utilize the qtsound module: vlc -vvv qtsound://

Win: Use sth like: vlc dshow:// :dshow-vdev="None" :dshow-adev="Your Audio Device"

Linux: Use sth like: vlc alsa://plughw:0,0

Comment: Thanks very much. Might give this ago later as I've abandoned the project for now.

Comment: @MichaelF.Could you put your response down as an answer so I can accept it? Cheers

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Which platform? I'm on Mac so i know for sure this is possible with VLC 2.0 for the other platforms this should work as well.

Haven't tested those commands though.

**Mac:** Use VLC 2.0.0 or later and utilize the qtsound module:

```
vlc -vvv qtsound://
```

**Win:** Use sth like:

```
vlc dshow:// :dshow-vdev="None" :dshow-adev="Your Audio Device"
```

**Linux:** Use sth like:

```
vlc alsa://plughw:0,0
```

Answer (score 9):

On Linux if you need to stream also video remember to separate all the options with ":" . In this case I am streaming the usb cam with the default alsa microphone.

```
cvlc v4l2:///dev/video0 :v4l2-standard=ALL :input-slave=alsa://hw:0,0 :live-caching=300  ':sout=#transcode{vcodec=mp4v,vb=3500,width=1920,height=1080,acodec=mp3,ab=192,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:http{mux=ts,dst=:8080/}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just my input on Linux. This works across the Internet as well

Get the mic device id

```
arecord -l
```

Streams to port 8080. Just remember on your router to put a port forward to this server

```
vlc alsa://plughw:1,0 --sout='#transcode{vcodec=none,acodec=mp3,ab=256,channels=2,samplerate=44100,scodec=none}:http{mux=mp3,dst=:8080/}' --no-sout-all --sout-keep
```

Comment: This works if I download the file in Safari, but in VLC it's just complete silence (no errors either). How can I play the stream in VLC as a client?